# How to upgrade RPM with rollback option enabled on centos?

Tags: python-2.7, shell, rpm, rpm-spec

I am using rpm for installing my application on centos. So to upgrade same rpm on centos I am planning to use "rpm -Uvh " command.

Does this command support inbuild rollback ?  I mean if my upgrade fails then how can i do the rollback ?

Comment: have a look here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7034

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK rpm --rollback and --repackage was removed from rpm around RHEL6 (maybe even in RHEL5). So recent OS does not support transaction by using only rpm command. The rpm itself now does not support transaction. It is left for tools built on top of rpm: Yum and DNF.

So on Centos you can run:

```
yum upgrade foo.rpm bar.rpm
```

and

```
yum history undo last
```

to rollback last transaction.

Comment: This means I need to maintain both the rpm in my repository for the upgrade. What else we can do to upgrade with new RPM But It should have rollback support ?

Comment: You either keep the package in repository or on client - by putting on client in /etc/yum.conf the setting `keepcache=1`.

Comment: what are cleanup steps required if  "rpm -Uvh  rpm_name" command failed?